# Im currently learning about algorithms in one of my CS classes. I am trying to write a code for QuickSort

Tags: c++, quicksort

Like the title says, I am trying to write a code for QuickSort, but I am trying to do this following a psuedocode given to us in the lecture. This isn't an assignment that's due it's just me trying to figure it out on my own. I've found a sample of QuickSort online, but it looks different than what our psuedocode says. The QuickSort code i found online uses pointers, i don't think pointers are mentioned in the given psuedocode. In other words, could someone check if im on the right path and maybe point out where I messed up. Thank you!

My code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Partition(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
   int x = arr[r];
   int i = p - 1;

   for (int j = p; j < r - 1; j++)
   {
      if (arr[j] <= x)
      {
         i = i + 1;
        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
      }

      swap(arr[i + 1], arr[r]);
   }

   return i + 1;
}

void Quicksort(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int k = Partition(arr, p, r);
        Quicksort(arr, p, k - 1);
        Quicksort(arr, k + 1, r);
    }
}

void print(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 3, 4, 9, 10 }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);


    Quicksort(arr, 0, n);
    print(arr, n);
    //I get an error here "Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted"
}
```

[This is the psuedocode for my QuickSort function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrUaS.png)
[Picture number two is the given psuedocode for my Partition function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXghW.png)

Comment: "This isn't an assignment that's due" to be clear, if it were an assignment that was due, that would be fine, as long as you ask a specific question in your question. This question is currently, "check my work, I don't know if it's good or not". We don't do that here. Either it's not compiling or it's crashing or the output doesn't match the expected output. We need a specific question.

Comment: Welcome to SO - there is actually another StackExchange network site for that purpose!: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ti7 this post might be perceived as not on-topic on CR because the author doesn't appear to know whether it works properly. Per the [on-topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "_**To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?** Code Review aims to help improve working code._"

Comment: Pro tip: print the actual values that get passed to `swap`, to make sure that they're ***always*** between 0-4, and then ponder the meaning of life if sometimes they're not.

Comment: Yep, asking us if your code works is pointless, because you define "works" yourself. As a new user here, please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Im not asking if it works.. Im asking if it matches the psuedocode I was given.

Comment: Looks like you have correctly implemented the given pseudocode. Note: it doesn't quite look like [a Hoare or a Lomuto quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). I'd have to play with it for a while to know if the pseudocode is optimal and correct.

Comment: Thanks for actually taking the time to respond and look over the code and psuedocode. That's pretty much all I wanted to hear. I figured I implemented it correctly, but I felt maybe the psuedocode is whats off about it. Which is why I wanted to check with other people

Comment: `j < r - 1` might be wrong. C++ array indexing is origin 0, so `j<r` might be sufficient. That won't cause the error you reported, though.  *Stack corruption around ...* usually means an array boundary has been breached. Use Sam's suggestion above: print all of the indexes swapped and see who walked out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In Partition(), if *i* is never incremented, then a swap(arr[p-1], ...) is done, probably the cause of the stack error. Normally, quick sort parameters are first and last index, as opposed to first and end (= last+1) index, in this case, Quicksort(arr, 0, n-1). The inner loop is looking for values < pivot (not <= pivot). The final swap needs to be done after the for loop. Fixes noted in comments.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Partition(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    int x = arr[r];
    int i = p;                          // fix
    for (int j = p; j < r; j++)         // fix
    {
        if (arr[j] < x)                 // fix
        {
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            i = i + 1;                  // fix
        }
    }
    swap(arr[i], arr[r]);               // fix
    return i;                           // fix
}

void Quicksort(int arr[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int k = Partition(arr, p, r);
        Quicksort(arr, p, k - 1);
        Quicksort(arr, k + 1, r);
    }
}

void print(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 3, 4, 9, 10 }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    Quicksort(arr, 0, n-1);             // fix
    print(arr, n);
    return 0;                           // fix
}
```

Comment: As I suspected. The pseudocode was wrong in a few places and misleading in others.